# Jupyter Octave Kernel on Windows7

Tags: octave, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, oct2py

Followed the instructions at https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel to install octave_kernel on a Windows1 machine and everything went ok.  However, when I select Octave as my kernal from Jupyter, the following occurs.

> The kernel has died, and the automatic restart has failed. It is
>   possible the kernel cannot be restarted. If you are not able to
>   restart the kernel, you will still be able to save the notebook, but
>   running code will no longer work until the notebook is reopened.

I also cannot get oct2py to work.

The Jupyter console output from the octave_kernal attempt follows.

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
[I 18:00:38.987 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel f15e40d3-8288-4b9b-bb32-dea6b67484e1 restarted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\octave_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in <m
odule>
    IPKernelApp.launch_instance(kernel_class=OctaveKernel)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 59
5, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-123>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 74
, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 421, in ini
tialize
    self.init_kernel()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 360, in ini
t_kernel
    user_ns=self.user_ns,
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 4
05, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\metakernel\process_metakernel.py", line 5
3, in __init__
    self._start()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\metakernel\process_metakernel.py", line 5
8, in _start
    self.wrapper = self.makeWrapper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\octave_kernel\kernel.py", line 82, in mak
eWrapper
    if 'version 4' in self.banner:
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\octave_kernel\kernel.py", line 63, in ban
ner
    banner = subprocess.check_output([self.executable, '--version'])
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 696, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
[W 18:00:42.002 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 18:00:42.002 NotebookApp] Kernel f15e40d3-8288-4b9b-bb32-dea6b67484e1 died, r
emoving from map.
ERROR:root:kernel f15e40d3-8288-4b9b-bb32-dea6b67484e1 restarted failed!
[W 18:00:42.002 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 18:00:42.002 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/d25e7956-2a56-4977-a2de-8b
9c3f828a05 (::1) 0.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled6.ipynb?
kernel_name=octave
```

I saw the permission error and tried to run Jupyter as an administrator to no avail.

Comment: Can you run `octave` or `octave-cli` at a command prompt?

Comment: Hi Thomas, Yes.  Windows has no problem finding Octave, either directly from run or from PowerShell or cmd in any directory.

I have both Octave and Jupyter installed directly in C:\ and I am wondering if that is the problem, even though I have administrator privileges.

Comment: I also tried the following in a Python console in administrator mode:  
`import subprocess, os
     executable = os.environ['OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE']
     subprocess.check_output([executable, '--version'])`

same error:

   `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`

Comment: What is OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE set to?

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda and Octave in:  `C:\ ` ;  `C:\Program Files\ `  ;  `C:\users\myusername\ ` ; `C:\users\myusername\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\ ` .  
In each case I make sure that myusername has full permissions to the folders and children, reset the PATH and OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE to the folder where `octave.exe` is (Anaconda resets itself), and reinstall Octave_Kernel.  Always get the same error.

Comment: I would guess that `OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE` should point to the executable, not the folder that contains it.

Comment: Finally got it to work.  Pretty sure the problem was having the both the system and user `PATH` variable set to the path to Octave. Also just deleted the `OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE` variable, but I tried that before and it made no difference.

Comment: I think `OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE` takes precedence, so if that was set to the wrong thing (like a directory), that would probably prevent any other fix working.

Answer (score 0):

Set enviornment variale OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE as C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin\octave-cli-4.2.1.exe. Provide full R/W permission to user Everyone on Octave install folder